# Passing empty object as argument becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, object, meteor, undefined

If I pass an empty object as an argument to a publication with

```
Template.taskList.onCreated( () => {
  var selector = {};
  Template.instance().subscribe( 'tasks', selector );
} );
```

and print the selector containing the empty object in the console with

```
Meteor.publish( 'tasks', function ( selector ) {
  console.log( selector );
  return Tasks.find( selector );
});
```

it says that `selector` is undefined instead of being an empty object.

Comment: Isn't it a bug in Meteor if I changes an empty object to undefined?

Comment: So, with a template level subscription, looks like DDP is not passing the empty object,  Template.instance().subscribe('data', {});  ["{\"msg\":\"sub\",\"id\":\"MdECcEF9AahMPXtsh\",\"name\":\"data\",\"params\":[]}"]  .   Whereas if you call Meteor.subscribe('data',{}) ,  the empty object is passed : ["{\"msg\":\"sub\",\"id\":\"e4njBoBgTP46M9YyQ\",\"name\":\"data\",\"params\":[{}]}"] .   so, yeah maybe it is a Meteor bug.